# How to provide context of failed assertion in mocha

Tags: javascript, dynamic, mocha.js

If I use mocha.js with [dynamically generated tests](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests), then how do I print out context of what were variable values when test failed?

If we take that example from mocha.js documentation,

```
var assert = require('assert');

function add() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr;
  }, 0);
}

describe('add()', function() {
  var tests = [
    {args: [1, 2],       expected: 3},
    {args: [1, 2, 3],    expected: 6},
    {args: [1, 2, 3, 4], expected: 10}
  ];

  tests.forEach(function(test) {
    it('correctly adds ' + test.args.length + ' args', function() {
      var res = add.apply(null, test.args);
      assert.equal(res, test.expected);
    });
  });
});
```

then how do I print out `{args: [1, 2, 3], expected: 6},` if second test fails?

Comment: does `assert.equal` take a third parameter `message`? I do not know these Javascript Testing frameworks good enough, but most others allow you to specify a message with every assert. You could then write something like `assert.equal(res, test.expected, "args: " + test.args);`

Comment: it works! thanks. can you form it as an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an additional parameter `message` to the assert.XYZ methods which will be output when the assert fails. You can add your desired output there

```
tests.forEach(function(test) {
    it('correctly adds ' + test.args.length + ' args', function() {
        var res = add.apply(null, test.args);
        assert.equal(res, test.expected, "Failed with data " + JSON.stringify(test));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass additional comments as third argument for `assert` method

```
  tests.forEach(function(test) {
    it('correctly adds ' + test.args.length + ' args', function() {
      var res = add.apply(null, test.args);
      assert.equal(res, test.expected, JSON.stringify(test)); // third argument passed
    });
  });
```

will produce output like:

> ```
> 1) add() correctly adds 3 args:
>
>   AssertionError: {"args":[1,2,3],"expected":8}
>   + expected - actual
>
>   -6
>   +8
> ```